# nested json with restkit on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, restkit

just trying to get used to restkit for iphone apps here at the moment and ive hit a wall. Im trying to get data from a nested json file.

```
[
{"person": {
    "name": "joe",
    "id": "1234",
    "numbers":
        [
            {"value": "555-12125"},
            {"value": "222-12125"}
        ]
    }
}]
```

i set up the rkobjectmanager like so

```
RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:3000"];  
[manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/J.json?user_id=36995582&planner=insta-grammar" objectClass:[Person class] delegate:self] ;

[manager registerClass:[Person class] forElementNamed:@"person"];
[manager registerClass:[Numbers class] forElementNamed:@"numbers"];
```

then the person class and numbers class as follows

```
#import "Person.h"


@implementation Person

@synthesize _name,_id,_number;

+ (NSDictionary*)elementToPropertyMappings {  
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:  
            @"name",@"name",
            @"id",@"id",nil];  
}  




+ (NSDictionary*)elementToRelationshipMappings {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:
            @"numbers", @"numbers",
            nil];
}

@end


#import "Numbers.h"


@implementation Numbers

@synthesize _number;

+ (NSDictionary*)elementToPropertyMappings {  
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:  
            @"value",@"value",nil];  
}  

+ (NSString*)primaryKeyProperty {
    return @"value";
}
+ (NSDictionary*)relationshipToPrimaryKeyPropertyMappings {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"value" forKey:@"value"];
}



@end
```

but every time the _number remains empty after the didloadobjects function is called while the name and id variables fill up fine.
any ideas on this?.
ive tried the example on git but couldnt get it to work so any help would be appreciated.
thanks
g

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to declare an `NSArray *_numbers` member variable in Person.h, make it a property like `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *_numbers` and synthesize it in Person.m like `@synthesize numbers = _numbers`. Then you can get rid of whatever _number is, since you won't be storing a single number object, you will be storing an array of number objects.

Your Numbers class should instead just be Number, and you should synthesize your number variable like `@synthesize number = _number;`. So your Number.m should look like

```
@implementation Number
@synthesize number = _number;

+ (NSDictionary *)elementToPropertyMappings {  
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:  
            @"value", @"number", nil];  
}
```

Because your property is number, the mapping dictionary value is `@"number"`, while your source JSON key should be `@"value"`.

Then you can load the objects like (note we are using our `Number` class for the `@"numbers"` element):

```
RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:3000"];
[manager registerClass:[Person class] forElementNamed:@"person"];
[manager registerClass:[Number class] forElementNamed:@"numbers"];

[manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/J.json?user_id=36995582&planner=insta-grammar" delegate:self];
```

For a full example see the [Catalog Example](https://github.com/twotoasters/RestKit/tree/master/Examples/RKCatalog/Examples/RKRelationshipMappingExample) int the RestKit github project

Comment: No its still not working. in fact the number class never even gets called. ive tried the catalog example and used its classes instead of mine and called them the same way as in the example and still no joy. it still only loads in non array data.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone following up on this. Finally got this all working using the new OM2 that they have just released with restkit. very nice and easy to use change

Comment: In my opinion, I think you should have accepted bensnider's answer rather than your own since he answered your particular question.  True, OM2 is a better way to go but his answer dealt with the circumstance presented in your question.

Comment: i see your point but i tried it the way bensnider said and it still didnt work for me. the answer he gave may have been 100% right but if it didnt work for me i dont see how i can vote it as right sorry.